# Parent Child relation - Sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My source is as follows

```
OSPID     OSPNAME RELATEDOSPID
100004  LEVEL4  100003
100003  LEVEL3  100002
100002  LEVEL2  100001
100001  LEVEL1  0
100009  LEVEL4  100008
100008  LEVEL2  100007
```

I need the result as

```
L4OSPID L4OSPNAME   L3RELATEDID L3OSPNAME   L2RELATEDID L2OSPNAME   L1RELATEDID L2OSPNAME   ROOTNODE
100004   LEVEL4      100003      LEVEL3      100002      LEVEL2      100001      LEVEL1        0
100009   LEVEL4      100008      NULL        NULL        LEVEL2      100007      NULL         NULL
```

If any level in between is missing should put NULL

Thanks

Comment: Are there always those 4 levels (except for the missing records)?

Comment: Peter: Yes there may be records with all 4 levels linked and will also be records with missing links in between.

Comment: Your last row points to `100007` which does not exist. Is this an error with your samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are only 4 LEVEL and that you always want to start from LEVEL4, here is the query

```
select L4.OSPID as L4OSPID, L4.OSPNAME as L4OPSNAME,
L4.RELATEDOSPID
 as L3RELATEDID,

case 
    WHEN L3.OSPNAME = 'LEVEL3' THEN L3.OSPNAME
    ELSE NULL
end as L3OSPNAME,

case 
    WHEN L3.OSPNAME = 'LEVEL3' THEN L3.RELATEDOSPID
    ELSE NULL
end as L2RELATEDID,

case 
    WHEN L3.OSPNAME = 'LEVEL2' THEN L3.OSPNAME
    WHEN L2.OSPNAME = 'LEVEL2' THEN L2.OSPNAME
    ELSE NULL
end as L2OSPNAME,

case WHEN L3.OSPNAME = 'LEVEL2' THEN  L3.RELATEDOSPID
    WHEN L2.OSPNAME = 'LEVEL2' THEN  L2.RELATEDOSPID
    ELSE NULL
end
 as L1RELATEDID,

case 
    WHEN L3.OSPNAME = 'LEVEL1' THEN L3.OSPNAME
    WHEN L2.OSPNAME = 'LEVEL1' THEN L2.OSPNAME
    WHEN L1.OSPNAME = 'LEVEL1' THEN L1.OSPNAME
    ELSE NULL
end as L1OSPNAME,

case 
    WHEN L3.OSPNAME = 'LEVEL1' THEN L3.RELATEDOSPID
    WHEN L2.OSPNAME = 'LEVEL1' THEN L2.RELATEDOSPID
    WHEN L1.OSPNAME = 'LEVEL1' THEN L1.RELATEDOSPID
    ELSE NULL
end as ROOTNODE


from osptable as L4

left outer join osptable as L3
on L4.RELATEDOSPID = L3.OSPID
left outer join osptable as L2
on L3.RELATEDOSPID = L2.OSPID
left outer join osptable as L1
on L2.RELATEDOSPID = L1.OSPID
where L4.OSPNAME = 'LEVEL4'
```

This gave me this result, which i think is the one desired

```
100004  LEVEL4  100003  LEVEL3  100002  LEVEL2  100001  LEVEL1  0
100009  LEVEL4  100008  NULL    NULL    LEVEL2  100007  NULL    NULL
```